# Laravel Eloquent create method causing integrity constraint violation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I've got the following eloquent models and relations set up:

Applicant

```
class Applicant {
    public function application()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Application::class);
    }
}
```

Application

```
class Application {
    public function applicant()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Applicant::class);
    }

    protected $fillable = [
        // ... other fields
        'applicant_id',
    ];
}
```

And their migrations:

`applicants` table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('applicants', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        // other fields ...    
    });
}
```

`applications` table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('applications', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        // other fields ...
        $table->integer('applicant_id')->unsigned();

        // other relations ...
        $table->foreign('applicant_id')->references('id')->on('applications')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

I simply want to create a new applicant then add a new application for the applicant just created:

```
$applicant = Applicant::create([
    // data
]);

$application = $applicant->applications()->create([
    // data
]);
```

However, when running this code I receive the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 
1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (
    `dbname`.`applications`, CONSTRAINT `applications_applicant_id_foreign` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`applicant_id`) REFERENCES `applications` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
(SQL: insert into `applications` (
    `status`,
    `reference_number`,
    `organisation_id`,
    `qualification_id`,
    `applicant_id`,
    `updated_at`,
    `created_at`
) values (
    pending,
    573066CE59BFE,
    24,
    1,
    12, // <------ applicant_id, i.e. the foreign key!
    2016-05-09 11:30:38,
    2016-05-09 11:30:38
))
```

As I understand, the error is occuring because I'm passing it a foreign key that doesn't exist in the database. So I was wondering what is happening here with the first call to the DB that I make to create the applicant:

```
$applicant = Applicant::create([
    // data
]);
```

Is it not written to the DB before the second statement that creates the application:

```
$application = $applicant->application()->create([
    // data
]);
```

... and thus causing the integrity constraint violation? Because if I `dd($applicant)` immediately after creating it or `dd(Applicant::find($applicant->id))` I get the record and I can also view it in the DB.

I've found that prior to re-factoring my code when I was calling `create()` to add a new record then building up a new application line by line and using `save()`, I didn't encounter this issue. So I'm curious to know how both calls differ (if they do) and what would be the correct way to approach such a scenario as I thought it was something very simple with eloquent which I've done many times before. Any advice would be most appreciated, thanks!

**Edit 1**

Corrected call to relation:

`$applicant->application()->create(...)`

not:

`$applicant->applications()->create(...)`

**Edit 2**

Running this code:

```
$applicant = Applicant::create($this->applicantDataFromRequest($request));

$application = new Application([
    'status'           => 'pending',
    'reference_number' => $request->get('passport_number'),
    'organisation_id'  => $request->get('organisation'),
    'qualification_id' => $request->get('qualification') ?: null,
]);

$applicant->application()->save($application);

dd('done');
```

And receiving the same error (updated with all errors on page):

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dbname`.`applications`, CONSTRAINT `applications_applicant_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`applicant_id`) REFERENCES `applications` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `applications` (`status`, `reference_number`, `organisation_id`, `qualification_id`, `applicant_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (pending, 5730970933C7B, 24, 1, 22, 2016-05-09 14:56:25, 2016-05-09 14:56:25))

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dbname`.`applications`, CONSTRAINT `applications_applicant_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`applicant_id`) REFERENCES `applications` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

**Edit 3**
Added relevant migrations

**Update 1**

Really strange! I've reverted back to an older version of the project via git where it was working before I began re-factoring my code and now that's not working for the same reason! No clue what's going on here!?

**Update 2**

Just noticed something really silly in the migrations:

`applications` table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('applications', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        // other fields ...
        $table->integer('applicant_id')->unsigned();

        // other relations ...
        $table->foreign('applicant_id')->references('id')->on('applications')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

The foreign key should be:

```
$table->foreign('applicant_id')
    ->references('id')
    ->on('applicants')
    ->onDelete('cascade'); // not applications!
```

Two points here:

1. Why did this not effect my code til now? It's been working fine til now weird...
2. Going to update the foreign key constraint and try it out to see if it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the migrations the foreign key constraint was referencing the wrong foreign table (it was actually referencing itself), a silly mistake!

The erroneous code for the `create_applications_table` migration:

```
$table->foreign('applicant_id')
    ->references('id')
    ->on('applications') // wrong table
    ->onDelete('cascade');
```

The correct code:

```
$table->foreign('applicant_id')
    ->references('id')
    ->on('applicants') // correct table
    ->onDelete('cascade');
```

This now works just fine:

```
$applicant = Applicant::create([
    // data
]);

$application = $applicant->applications()->create([
    // data
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$applicant = new Applicant([
    // data
]);

$application = new Application([
    // data
]);

$applicant->applications()->save($application);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, will give it a try soon. Any idea why this doesn't work with the `create` method?

Comment: You can create both models with `create()`, but I guess you still need to use `save()` to save One-To-One relationship. `create()` just creates instance of model: https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.php#L310

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same issue while using the create method yesterday. Trying to save to two models from 1 form and receiving the same integrity constraint error.

If you're using create, you can instantiate your applicant first:

```
$applicant = Applicant::create(//applicant data);
$application = new Application(//application data);
$applicant->application()->save($application);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kevin. Still can't seem to get it working strangely, see my question updated. Thanks.

Comment: Is the error in your edit#2 the only exception you receive or are there more at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Hi Haakym - Please post your migration code for the application and applicant models (just need to see how `application.applicant_id` and `applicant.id` are set up)

Comment: Sure thing! Will post it up now.

Comment: Try keeping the `id` column in both models as the same type i.e. unsigned integers

Comment: So you're saying primary key for applicant needs to be `unsigned` not sure how that would help?

Comment: Its best to have the same data type on both columns, signed or unsigned, as long as its consistent across any fields that require a foreign key relationship.

Comment: Sorry my point is that I don't believe adding that to my migrations, migrating the db again, then running the code again would make any difference.

Comment: Turns out I was referencing the wrong table on the foreign key, such a silly mistake! Thanks for your suggestions!